# Angular 6 subscribe: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to find out if a returned value from a service is in an array.

I have this code in my `component.ts` file.

```
this.addressService.getPostcodeData(postcode)
    .subscribe((v) => {
       if (this.allowedLocalAreaCodes.includes(v.result.codes.admin_district)) {
        console.log('yes');
      }
```

However, I am getting the error:

> Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

If I console log that value above the if statement. I get the right code. This returns:

> E07000179

if I wrap it in an if to see if there is a value first like so:

```
 if (v.result.codes.admin_district) {
    console.log(v.result.codes.admin_district);
  }
```

I also get:

> E07000179

then I do:

```
 if (v.result.codes.admin_district) {

    console.log(v.result.codes.admin_district);
    if (this.allowedLocalAreaCodes.includes(v.result.codes.admin_district)) {
        console.log('yes');
    }
  }
```

and I get the error.

For some reason the include fails. Anyone know why?

Edit: allowedLocalAreaCodes is:

```
allowedLocalAreaCodes = ['E06000028', 'E09000025', 'E09000030', 'E09000012', 'S12000036', 'S12000046'];
```

Comment: what does `allowedLocalAreaCodes` look like? The issue is most likely how you are accessing it within the subscription block

Comment: The issue is with `this.allowedLocalAreaCodes`.

Comment: this.allowedLocalAreaCodes is null. Assign "this" instance to a variable before calling subscribe function.

Comment: Please see edit @MikeTung

Comment: @VireshMathad ^

Comment: @PrerakSola see edit :)

Comment: `this.allowedLocalAreaCodes` clearly undefined there for some reason. 
console log it before if. Better if you just put a breakpoint and check it, also check what `this` is really are .

Comment: I would console log the `v` in `subscribe`

Comment: I don't see you setting `allowedLocalAreaCodes` anywhere.

Comment: @Mark Assign "this" to a variable and use.

let instance = this;
this.addressService.getPostcodeData(postcode)
    .subscribe((v) => {
       if (instance.allowedLocalAreaCodes.includes(v.result.codes.admin_district)) {
        console.log('yes');
      }